# Is it possible to use fontawesome icons with ipyvuetify?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vuetify.js, voila

I created a button in my notebook using the [doc](https://ipyvuetify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#icons) :

```py
import ipyvuetify as v

#validate the selected data 
v.Container(children=[
    v.Btn(color='primary', children=[
        v.Icon(left=True, children=[
            'mdi-email-edit-outline'
        ]),
        'Click me'
    ])
])
```

Now, instead of using the mdi library I'd like to use a fontAwesome icon like :

```py
#validate the selected data 
v.Container(children=[
    v.Btn(color='primary', children=[
        v.Icon(left=True, children=[
            'fab fa-500px'
        ]),
        'Click me'
    ])
])
```

but the `fa` lib is unrecognized.
is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ipyvuetify doesn't ship with fontawesome icons. Seeing [Christoph Weiss-Schabers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14442791/christoph-weiss-schaber) answer it does seem to work accidentally if fontawesome is loaded on the page either when you use JupyterLab or an extension that uses fontawesome.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to your installation.
You should update ipyvuetify and check if this icon-set you want to use is installed.

When I tried your code it ran out of the box as far a I can tell:
[image]

Comment: My ipyvuetify version is the latest And still don't see the icons of fa. Did you do it on fresh conda install ? did you had already fa installed ? 
I checked the [package.json file](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify/blob/master/js/package.json) and I see mdi icons. fa is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we just need to load font awesome, either first need to pip install e.g. :

```
from IPython.display import HTML
display(HTML('''
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../site-packages/notebook/static/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" />
 '''))
```